# Python error: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,10) into shape (10)

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code and get this error: 
S[i+1,:]  = (S[i,:] + np.cumsum(np.sqrt(dt)*np.random.randn(nsims),axis=0)) + epsilon_plus*np.random.poisson(lambda_plus,(M,nsims))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,10) into shape (10)

```py
sigma = 0.1
dt = 0.05
lambda_plus = 2
lambda_minus = 2
M = 20 #number of steps
epsilon_plus = 1.0/2
epsilon_minus = 1.0/2   
T = 1
nsims = 10
s = 100
S = s*np.ones((M,nsims))

def price(lambda_plus, lambda_minus, M, T, dt, nsims):
    for i in range(M-1):
        S[i+1,:]  = (S[i,:] + np.cumsum(np.sqrt(dt)*np.random.randn(nsims),axis=0)) + epsilon_plus*np.random.poisson(lambda_plus,(M,nsims))
    return S
```

The error occurs when I add the part of epsilon_plus*np.random.poisson(lambda_plus,(M,nsims)). How can I add this part to S?

Comment: Please make a minimal example, also tell us what line the error occurs in.

Comment: This looks a lot like a question that was posted a day or two ago, except now `S1` is made into an array before use in the equation.  But it has the same problem.  `S` is a (201,1) shape array, so `S[t]` is shape (1,).  The equation produces an array with shape (201,).  That doesn't fit!  What is that equation supposed to calculate?  One value for index `t`, or many values?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this expression:

```
S[t-1] + sigma*math.sqrt(dt)*A + epsilon_plus*B-epsilon_minus*C
```

All three terms you're adding `sigma*math.sqrt(dt)*A`,  `epsilon_plus*B`, and `epsilon_minus*C` have shape `(201,)`, and so does the result after adding to `S[t-1]` - but you're trying to assign it to `S[t]`, which has shape `(1,)`.

You need to explain what exactly you expect to store in `S[t]` for me to provide a solution - I don't want to reverse engineer / guess intent from your code.